# Able to get element length but not innerHTML

Tags: javascript, function

I am using a function to in which i have some elements and on click of that elements i need to find innerHTML of some other elements.

Problem i am facing is i am able to find the length of that element but in same way when i am trying to get innerHTML of the same element its showing undefined.

**My function**

```
var question = document.querySelectorAll('.questions li a');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
  question[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction)
}

function myFunction() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('need_help')
  alert(div.length);
  //alert(div.innerHTML);
}
```

Here is the example where i am finding length and its working fine : https://jsfiddle.net/uw0nsf4g/

This is the example where i am finding innerHTML and its showing undefined : https://jsfiddle.net/uw0nsf4g/1/

Please tell me what is wrong with the code if element is searchable then why not its innerHTML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: libraries like jquery will create a context which effectively let you get and set the inner html from the selector.
I would imagine `var div = document.getElementsByClassName('need_help')` is only a array (of node elements) and you would need to itterate over the elements or just pick the first: div[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the length returned is the length of the array with elements; try the following:

```
var question = document.querySelectorAll('.questions li a');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
    question[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction)
}

function myFunction() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('need_help');
    for(var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
        alert(divs[j].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any other way to get the element rather than `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll` because they always gives an array and then we need to use loop n all?

Comment: I think i dont need to ask another question for it...if you can help..i want to get height of next sibling of this. i am using `alert(this.nextSibling.style.height)` but its giving error in console **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined**

Comment: for your array issue...if you know you'll only get one result, you can use document.getElementsByClassName("AClass")[0]

Answer (score 2):

With the `getElementsByClassName` Function you get an Array od Elements. You just need to get the Index you want and alert the innerHTML.
Example:

```
function myFunction() {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('need_help')
    alert(div.length);
    alert(div[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it returns an array.

```
alert(div[0].innerHTML);
```

would work

Comment: If you read the question properly ,he's trying div.innerHTML
whereas it returns an array and the div has only one tag inside. 
So if he writes  alert(div[0].innerHTML); , it will work. That's what i have told

Answer (score 1):

DOM API function `getElementsByClassName()` returns an Array like Object.
so your call to this function is returning an array. `inner.HTML` property will work with DOM node not on array of DOM nodes...
You need to select an element from the array to get its content
you can loop through all of the nodes to get their content or you can use first element from this array in the above case as shown below:

```
var question = document.querySelectorAll('.questions li a');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
    question[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('need_help');
    alert(div[0].innerHTML);
}

OR loop through all of the elements to get their content:

function myFunction() {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('need_help');
    for(var k = 0; k < div.length; k++) {
        alert(div[k].innerHTML);
    }
}
```